# Dropdown option getting selected when it should not

Tags: html, laravel, date, dropdown, html-select

**Current code** for selecting birthday dates

```
<label>Birthday</label>
<select name="dob-year" id="dob-year" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>Year</option>
  <option value="" disabled>----</option>
...
  <option value="1971" {{date("Y", strtotime($friend->birthday)) == '1971' ? 'selected' : ''}}>1971</option>
  <option value="1970" {{date("Y", strtotime($friend->birthday)) == '1970' ? 'selected' : ''}}>1970</option>
  <option value="1969" {{date("Y", strtotime($friend->birthday)) == '1969' ? 'selected' : ''}}>1969</option>
...
</select>
<select name="dob-month" id="dob-month" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>Month</option>
  <option value="" disabled>-----</option>
  <option value="01" {{date("F", strtotime($friend->birthday)) == 'January' ? 'selected' : ''}}>01</option>
  <option value="02" {{date("F", strtotime($friend->birthday)) == 'February' ? 'selected' : ''}}>02</option>
...
</select>
<select name="dob-day" id="dob-day" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>日</option>
  <option value="" disabled>---</option>
  <option value="01" {{date("d", strtotime($friend->birthday)) == '01' ? 'selected' : ''}}>01</option>
  <option value="02" {{date("d", strtotime($friend->birthday)) == '02' ? 'selected' : ''}}>02</option>
...
</select>
```

**What I want to do**
is to add `{{$friend->birthday == null ? 'selected' : ''}}` like below in each Year/Month/Day tags

```
<select name="dob-year" id="dob-year" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>Year</option>
  <option value="" {{$friend->birthday == null ? 'selected' : ''}} disabled>----</option>
...
</select>
```

**The problem**
This a weird one I cant seem to find the issue that is causing this.
Ive disabled all javascript and double checked what is being returned from controller too but cannot find the source of the issue.

The default selected values of Year/Month/Day is always 1970/01/01 even if I hard code `selected` on other options. For example `<option value="" selected>Year</option>` would have it only select 1970.
If I delete the whole 1970 option tag only then everything works fine. So for this to work I had to delete 1970 option tag, 01 January option tag and 01 day option tag. Which is no use...

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: What's the format of `birthday` ? @haashe

Comment: Format of `birthday` is 1970-01-01 @MuhammadShareyar

Comment: @haashe I [believe I found your main problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71338686/295783)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to the format you are giving to `strtotime()` function, when giving any unsupported format to

```
echo date('Y/d/m',strtotime("20/03/03"));
echo date('Y:d:m',strtotime(null))

it will return you default value which is `1970/01/01`
```

you are passing either wrong format or null as parameter to `strtotime()`

**Suggestion**

You can do something like this, where you want to show the dropdown get dbirthday into a variable and check if it is `null` or not, and then update your `$year, $day, $month` value in that case if value is null it will not select any value and on right value it will select the option is correct.

```
 @php
    $friendBD =  '';
    $day = '';
    $month = '';
    $year = '';
@endphp


@foreach ($friends as $friend)

    @php
        $friendBD =  $friend->birthday
    @endphp
    
    @if(!is_null($friendBD))
        @php
            $date = \Carbon\Carbon::create($friendBD);
            $month = $date->format('M');
            $day = $date->format('d');
            $year = $date->format('Y');
        @endphp
    @endif


    <label>Birthday</label>
    <select name="dob-year" id="dob-year" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Year</option>
    <option value="" disabled>----</option>
    <option value="1971" >1971</option>
    <option value="1970" {{$year == '1970' ? 'selected' : ''}}>1970</option>
    <option value="1969" {{$year == '1969' ? 'selected' : ''}}>1969</option>
    <option value="2020" {{$year == '2020' ? 'selected' : ''}}>2020</option>
    </select>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Umm I see.. Is there a good way to solve this?

Comment: @haashe I have updated the answer for some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP might be invalid

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb07478fd5cc5da9535750524631d0c78763fe11

If you have

```
$friend['birthday'] = "1980/02/01";
```

or

```
$friend = array("birthday"=>"1980/02/01");
```

then you need to access the birthday like this

```
echo strtotime($friend["birthday"]);
```

So your statements need to look like this

```
echo date("Y", strtotime($friend["birthday"]));

echo date("F", strtotime($friend["birthday"]));

echo date("d", strtotime($friend["birthday"]));
```

If you do NOT access the string correctly, your will get 1970, January, 01 for any date. In my case since I am in GMT+1, I get 1969, December, 31 for the "0" date resulting from an invalid date passed to strtotime

Alternatively use JavaScript:

```js
const dob = "1971/02/01" // "<?= $friend["birthday"] ?>";
const [yyyy,mm,dd] = dob.split("/")
document.getElementById("dob-year").value=yyyy;
document.getElementById("dob-month").value=mm;
document.getElementById("dob-day").value=dd;
```

```html
<label>Birthday</label>
<select name="dob-year" id="dob-year" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>Year</option>
  <option value="" disabled>----</option>
  <option value="1971">1971</option>
  <option value="1970">1970</option>
  <option value="1969">1969</option>
</select>
<select name="dob-month" id="dob-month" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>Month</option>
  <option value="" disabled>-----</option>
  <option value="01" 01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
</select>
<select name="dob-day" id="dob-day" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>日</option>
  <option value="" disabled>---</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think he wants to select the right option using ternary operation in blade

Comment: Sure, but then he has to use the correct format. My code is simpler